# Doing download job in background while allow user to continue using my app

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-download-manager

This come up during my project, i'm building an android application, one of its functions is to allow user to start a file download, the file will be downloaded to my server space, then a batch file will process the download file, after file has been converted, upload the file into my android device, how can i realize these function ?

Currently I'm using a customized http client to call a php script at my server, trigger the downloading, then a folder monitor to scan the space, if found any new file, process them, but i have 2 problems now :
1: when doing the http request at my android site, if the file is large (several MBs) my app hangs for a while, which is not very user friendly (aync tast might not be suitable to use here since the file is not small, download takes quite some time)
2: after the server side generate the file i want i donno how to use program to upload to my device

Any advice ?

Comment: For 1.: If the tasks takes a while. Use a `Thread` instead of an `AsyncTask`. **Never** do big calculations or time-consuming tasks on your UI thread - as you have noticed, this lets the UI freeze.

Answer (score 0):

Start an IntentService to download the file. IntentService calls onHandleIntent in a worker thread already so all you have to care about is direct downloading.

[Creating a Background Service](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html)